# Merging two three column matrices: uniques in cols 1&2, maximum in col 3

Tags: matlab, matrix, merge, unique, set-union

I have two matrices:

```
a = [ 1 10 20; 2 11 22; 3 12 34; 4 13 12];
b = [ 3 12 1;  4 13 25; 5 14 60; 6 15 9 ];
```

I want to merge them into a single matrix where the rows with the maximum in column 3 used where columns 1 and 2 are identical, i.e. the resulting matrix should look like this:

```
 c = [ 1 10 20; 2 11 22; 3 12 34; 4 13 25; 5 14 60; 6 15 9];
```

Any suggestions how to do this easily in MATLAB would be greatly appreciated. I've banged my head on a wall trying to use `intersect` but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When merging the arrays you should make sure that they end up sorted (by col1 then col2 then col3). Fortunately, the `union` function does exactly that.

In your example, where the values in the 1st and 2nd columns are always unique, we can only observe the values in the 1st column to choose the correct rows. This happens when `diff` returns a nonzero value (which means this is the bottom row of a group):

```
a = [ 1 10 20; 2 11 22; 3 12 34; 4 13 12];
b = [ 3 12 1;  4 13 25; 5 14 60; 6 15 9];
c = [ 1 10 20; 2 11 22; 3 12 34; 4 13 25; 5 14 60; 6 15 9 ];

u = union(a,b,'rows');               % this merges and sorts the arrays
r = u(logical([diff(u(:,1)); 1]),:); % since the array is sorted, the last entry will have 
                                     % the maximum value in column 3
assert(isequal(r,c));
```

Comment: Brilliant! I knew there was an easier way than the embarrasing `for-if` solution I came up with! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a mix between `unique` and `accumarray`.

- Use `unique` to create an index based on the 2 first columns
- Use `accumarray` to find the maximum value in the third column according to the index.

The code:

```
a = [ 1 10 20;2 11 22; 3 12 34; 4 13 12];
b = [3 12 1; 4 13 25; 5 14 60; 6 15 9];

M = [a;b];
[res,~,ind] = unique(M(:,1:2),'rows');
c  = [res,accumarray(ind,M(:,3),[],@max)]
```

Answer (score -1):

Read about *unique*

```
a = [ 1 10 20;2 11 22; 3 12 34; 4 13 12];
b = [3 12 1; 4 13 25; 5 14 60; 6 15 9];

A = [a;b] ;
[c,ia,ib] = unique(A(:,1)) ;

C = A(ia,:)
```

Comment: How does this help with the intersect?

Comment: Your result doesn't match the expected result of the OP.